# How to capture rest api call performance metrics?

Tags: rest, api, jmeter

I have a rest api call, which i would like to measure the response times for each http call.
Can it be measured with JMeter and Blazemeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Measure Response times for rest http api calls you first need to create a Jmeter test plan using [http request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

Follow the steps below to create a test plan.

1. Open Apache Jmeter, Right click on Test Plan --> Add --> Threads --> Thread Group.
2. Right click on Thread Group --> Add --> Sampler--> HTTP Request.

[image]

3. Enter Server Address ,path and parameters. You can add any number of http samplers to a Thread group.
4. Save the test plan.

   You can run the Jmeter tests using [the link](https://www.redline13.com/StartTest) . Its very cheap and you can get the reports as well.
   here is the reference [link and instructions](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/jmeter/) on how to run a Jmeter test using AWS instances

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be. In the majority of cases REST is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) over [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP) so JMeter naturally supports sending REST requests via [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

You might also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in order to send [`Content-Type` Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

More information:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)